# Can the graph of a continuous function be a rotation of the graph of a discontinuous function?

Tags: gn.general-topology

Can there exist two functions $f,g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ so that $f$ is continuous, $g$ is discontinuous, and their graphs $\Gamma_f, \Gamma_g \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ are related by an isometry? (I think you can assume the isometry is a rotation.)

The graph of a continuous function must be path connected, so a natural intermediate question is, "can a discontinuous function have path connected graph?"

Comment: Are you sure that claim is valid for all (graphs of) continuous functions? How about a constant function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, say $x \mapsto 0$? Unless you rotate it by 90 degrees the graph will be a straight line and hence continuous, whereas if you rotate by 90 degrees it is not the graph of a function at all anymore. I think more details of the question are in order.

Comment: This sounds similar to taking the inverse of an injective bounded operator with dense range - this is usually not continuous and only densely defined. The graphs are rotations of one another, but it is not classical analysis..

Comment: Even now the question is poor: take $f(x)=x$ on $[0,1)$ and $x+1$ on $[1,2]$. Then $f$ is discontinuous and $f^{-1}$ is continuous (on their domains, of course). If we assume the set $S$ to be compact, then every function arising this way is continuous and the question is vacuous again. We can, probably, try to salvage it in some way but I prefer to leave that to OP.

Comment: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/828/can-the-graph-of-a-continuous-function-be-rotated-to-become-the-graph-of-a-discontinuous-function

Comment: As stated the answer is no.  The proof is an exercise in the intermediate value theorem. 

Comment: Thank you for the replies, they were very informative. This question, in its original form, was first raised by H. Thurston in the paper, "Can a graph be both continuous and discontinuous?"

http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=71698

Here however, the answer is in the affirmative (probably owing to some difference in terminology). Although, since I don't have acccess to the original I can not be sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the question has an easy answer, and it's essentially a 1st course in analysis type question that reduces pretty quickly to an intermediate value theorem application. Here's a more general statement. Let $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be continuous and $h : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ a homeomorphism. Then if $h(graph(f))$ is the graph of a function $g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, then $g$ is continuous.

Sketch: consider the function $P : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ given by $P(x) = \pi_1 \circ h(x,f(x))$, where $\pi_1(x,y)=x$. This is a continuous monotone function by the assumptions, so it is an open map by the intermediate value theorem, so it's inverse exists and is continuous. The claimed function $g$ is then $g(x)=\pi_2 h(P^{-1}(x), f(P^{-1}(x))$ where $\pi_2(x,y)=y$.

The question gives me the feeling it's a homework problem, but I've never seen it before. This was solved in meta, with a correction by Anton.  I wish I had known about this question yesterday -- I would have put it on my analysis class final exam!

Comment: I hadn't realized it earlier, but this argument (with slight modification) actually proves the stronger statement that the graph of a function is path connected if and only if the function is continuous. Very nice.

Answer (score 4):

The only meaning of the statement I can see is, the (quite obvious) fact that a 90 degrees rotation of the graph of a continuous, increasing function $f$ gives the graph of a function, plus the jumps.

Talking of rotating graphs, a more interesting fact is that  a 45 degree rotation transforms 1-Lipschitz graphs into monotone increasing graphs, and conversely. As a consequence, the theorems of a.e. differentiability for Lipschitz functions, and for monotone functions, can be deduced from each other.

Comment: Isn't f(x)=x 1-Lipschitz?

Comment: Isn't g(x)=0 increasing? 

Comment: @Pietro: do you mean"nondecreasing"?

Comment: @Pietro: if I'm interpreting your answer correctly, rotating the graph of f(x)=x gives a vertical line, not a horizontal one. If you meant the other rotation, then TonyK could ask "Isn't f(x)=-x 1-Lipschitz?" I think you need the function to be (1-ε)-Lipschitz, or to define the inequality in the definition of Lipschitz to be strict. Then you get a strictly increasing function.

Comment: Thierry: yes, of course (to me "increasing" means "f(x)≤f(x) whenever x≤y"; for the strict variant I use "strictly increasing"). @Anton: yes, of course. If we want to include 1-Lip, extended real-valued functions have to be considered. Given the nature of the question as given in the first version, it didn't seem to me the case of proposining more structured statements.

Comment: I'd like to endorse this answer by Pietro; I think it's possible that Herbert Wilf was recalling a bygone age when the notion of function had not yet been clearly formulated. See Lakatos's Proofs and Refutations, pp. 129-130, and footnote 2 on page 130. 
